# Listing zip archives using zip-conduit

Tags: haskell, zip, zip-conduit

Using the [`zip-conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-conduit) library, I want to list entries in a ZIP archive. I want to print them only filename per line - similar to `unzip -l`, but without any additional information.

**Note:** This question was answered using Q&A-style and therefore intentionally doesn't show any research effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`entryNames`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-conduit-0.2.2.1/docs/Codec-Archive-Zip.html#v:entryNames) function. By modifying [the ZIP extraction example](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zip-conduit-0.2.2.1/docs/Codec-Archive-Zip.html) we can print the names instead of extracting.

The following example program takes the ZIP file name from the first commandline parameter and uses `mapM_ putStrLn` to print them:

```
import Codec.Archive.Zip (withArchive, entryNames)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
    -- ZIP file name: First commandline arg
    zipPath:_ <- getArgs
    names <- withArchive zipPath $ entryNames
    mapM_ putStrLn names
```